# How to know if a JTable is empty?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Unlike most data structures, `JTable` does not have `isEmpty()` method. So how can we know if a given `JTable` doesn't contain any value?

Answer (score 7):

This will return actual number of rows, irrespective of any filters on table.

```
int count= jTable.getModel().getRowCount();
```

`jTable.getRowCount()` will return only visible row count. So to check isEmpty() then it's better to use `getRowCount()` on model.

```
public static boolean isEmpty(JTable jTable) {
        if (jTable != null && jTable.getModel() != null) {
            return jTable.getModel().getRowCount()<=0?true:false;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

```
table.getRowCount();
table.getColumnCount();
```

If either one is 0, then there is no data.

Comment: Technically, you should put it as "then there is no data **to display**". Either could return zero, but that doesn't mean that the underlying model doesn't contain any data.

Answer (score 0):

**you have a fixed number of columns .. suppose three**

```
public int Actualrows(DefaultTableModel m) {
        int row = 0;
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < m.getRowCount(); ++i) {

            try {
                if (!(m.getValueAt(i, 0).equals("")) && !(m.getValueAt(i, 1).equals(""))
                        && !(m.getValueAt(i, 2).equals(""))) {
                    row++;
                }

            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                continue;
            }


        }
        return row;
    }
```

**if the return value equal 0 its absolutely an empty table**

Answer (score -3):

Actually, there is no method for learning it my friend. But myself, using a method to learn whether it's empty or not.

At first, while you create `JTable` set the default row count `0`. When you want to use `JTable`, make the `JTable` with data which return count from the database. So if there is no `data.getRowCount()` will return `0` again. And so, you will know whether `JTable` is empty or not.

```
 try (ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query)) { 
     int colcount = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();//get's the  row count in the database
     DefaultTableModel tm = new DefaultTableModel();
     for (int i = 1; i <= colcount; i++) {
         tm.addColumn(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i));
     }
     while (rs.next()) {
        Object[] row = new Object[colcount];
        for (int i = 1; i <= colcount; i++) {
            row[i - 1] = rs.getObject(i);
        }
        tm.addRow(row);
     }
     jTblAd.setModel(tm);
     conn.close();
 }
```

Lastly i want to say that if the jTable has head,for example : Name-Surname-Age etc, `table.getRowCount(); table.getColumnCount();`not working because of head of jtable. So,my opinion is that if we cant check the jTable,check the Dataset which  be written in the table.

Comment: (1-) this code shows how to add data from a ResultSet to a table model. The question was about knowing when a "table" is empty. Where the data potentially came from is irrelevant.

Comment: As i first think say is that "There is no defined method for it,isnt it ?". I only want to show what i am doing whether jTable is empty or not. Logially,if there is no data return from database,jTable will empty right ? I think this way solves my problem and in my projects it's working.

Comment: It may solve your problem, but you didn't ask the question and you answer is off topic. The database is irrelevant. The question was about data in a JTable, not about whether a database query returns any data.