# How do you put a conditional if that pops a dialog based on jTable object?

Tags: java, swing, if-statement, jtable, jdialog

I am having trouble in java swing as I do not know how to make a conditional if that would pop up a `jDialog` based on the amount of object/rows in the `jTable`. How do you do that?

I have a dialog I want to pop out that shows an error message if there are no objects in the table and if there are then it would pop up another dialog that would allow the user to continue to the system process.

I don't know if it will help you guys understand my question more but here's my code:

```
private void billMousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
errorDialog.setVisible(true);
```

I want to put `errorDialog.setVisible(true)` inside a conditional if. It should only be visible if there are rows/objects inside the table model or objects < 1 but I don't know how to do it.

I tried

```
 if (cartTable.isEmpty()){
 errorDialog.setVisible(true);
 }
 else {
 payDialog.setVisible(true);
 }
```

and this is what it says:cannot find symbol
symbol: method is Empty()
location: variable cartTable of JTable

P.S Sorry if this is a dumb question, I am a complete newbie.

Comment: what part exactly is it you are having trouble with?

Comment: The conditional if. I don't know how to construct if that would pop up a jDialog, if the there are no objects/row in the table then this jDialog should pop up, if there are then this jDialog should pop up.

Comment: if ( table.isEmpty() ) {
  showPopup();
} Sure, it'll be a bit more expanded, but that's the basic idea

Comment: It doesn't work, unfortunately. It says the method is empty in the symbol.

Comment: I didn't give you copy-paste ready code, that's not what StackOverflow is for, I just pointed to the logic to follow

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find an answer here [How to know if a JTable is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30603531/how-to-know-if-a-jtable-is-empty)

Here's the answer to my question:

```
if (cartTable.getModel().getRowCount()<1) {
    errorDialog.setVisible(true);
    }
else {
    payDialog.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: A simpler version would be: boolean b = cartTable.getModel().getRowCount() < 1; errorDialog.setVisible(b); payDialog.setVisible(!b);